# pointers scope questions and return reference of pointer inside vector of pointers encapsulated in class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

I have some questions about pointers, scopes and pointers inside vector encapsulated in class

**i have this supposed cases and examples with questions:**

**Example 1**

1. the variable int y scope is inside the function and when the function finish and go away that returning reference will be died and that reference be referenced to nothing?

```
    int& createInt() {
        int y = 5;
        return y;
    }
```

**case1: if i do this in main or other function:**

```
    int x = createInt();
    std::cout << "x value \n";
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    // std::cout return 5
```

- this mean that im saving my own copy of the value of createInt()
  function that is 5 in the variable x, so is safe because int x contain their own value?
- but what happen with the reference returning from the createInt() function, is there a memory leak or not because is not a pointer a will die with the scope of the function.

**case 2: if i do this in main or other function:**

```
    int &x = createInt();
    std::cout << "x value \n";
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    // std::cout return 32767
```

- int &x is equals to the reference returning from createInt() function, that reference die when the function finish/go away so for that reason 
  int &x is returning a wrong value 32767 and not 5 or what are that 32767 value?

  - so int &x = createInt(); is evil and very bad practice because is reference to nothing.

**example 2**

what about this? i'm requesting allocation memory for int and initialized memory to the pointer variable...

```
    int& createInt() {
        int* y = new int(5);
        return *y;
    }
```

that pointer variable is in the stack but store a reference to the new int that is in the heap, so that new int will be alive when the scope of the function go away because is in the heap right?

so when i return the reference i'm returning the reference to that new int not the pointer variable, right? so is bad to returning the reference instead of the pointer? for what?

**case1: if i do this in main or other function:**

```
    int x = createInt();
    std::cout << "x value \n";
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    // std::cout return 5
```

i'm creating a copy of the new int value from createInt() in my local int x variable, so is this a memory leak because i'm creating a copy and not getting the pointer, so i can't do a delete of int x variable because is not a pointer, and also i can't delete the int *y pointer created inside createInt() function because the pointer is lost, i don't have it outside the createInt()

**but whats happen if i do:**

```
delete &x;
```

i will get a error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee204b8c8: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

because i'm deleting my int x that is not in the heap? or is trying to delete the int *y inside the createInt() function ?

**case2: if i do this with the same function:**

```
    int &x = createInt2();
    std::cout << "x value \n";
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    // std::cout return 5
```

my int &x is a reference of the returning by createInt()

so i can do:

```
delete &x;
```

is a memory leak here? but its so bad delete &x reference instead of the pointer int *y? maybe doing delete & i'm not have form to be sure if that is allocated memory or is stack memory, so good practice is never try to delete using &?

***vectors parts:***

i have a class A that contain a vector of pointers of class B, also i have a method that return a element of the vector but as reference *(because i want to have it in memory to reutilize it and control when is deleted like a connection pool also i move it from used vector to notInUsevector but this is other history)*, and in the destructor of class A i delete all the vector elements:

```
Class A {

//this is singleton

public:

 static A& getInstance() 
       {
            std::call_once(m_once, []() {
                instance.reset(new Database());
            });
            return *instance;
        }

 B& getFirstElement() {
    auto element = connections.front();
    return *element;
}

~A() {
   for(auto element : myVector){
    delete num;
   }
}

 A(A const &) = delete;

 void operator=(A const &) = delete;

private:
A();
static std::unique_ptr<A> instance;
static std::once_flag m_once;
std::vector<B*> myVector;

}
```

so in other place/function/class etc i do:

```
auto element = &A::getInstance().getFirstElement();
```

or maybe is best or the same:

```
 auto &element = A::getInstance().getFirstElement();
```

so when the Class A instance is deleted the destructor will delete all the pointers inside myVector

is this safe, there is a memory leak? it's a very bad return the reference in the getInstance() function instead of the pointer?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's make it clear, **scope** is "layer" between `{` and `}`. It might be a function body, statement (if, switch, for, etc.) or standalone scope. The most important consequence is that life time of objects created on stack is limited to that scope.
Take your function `createInt()` as example, internal `int y`, exists only inside of that function. The moment you reach `}` that memory is free.

Second thing is term **memory leak**. Memory leak is a situation where you have a chunk of memory (might be a single byte, might be a couple of pages) and no way to point at it. It's like a locked box without a key. It is there, it is yours memory, it won't be free unless you tell, problem is you don't know where that memory is located, you have no pointer for it.

That's being said, let's talk about your cases:

- Example 1 Case 1:

You are lucky. Your function return its internal `y` by reference, but this returned variable is freed before you return from your function. Effectively you have a value written down on sticky note, then you throw it to the trash and then return saying that your value is on that note that is in trash. The only reason you can still read it is because no one assigned that bit of memory in the mean time and it was not overwritten. Remember, the moment your function reached `}` all stack alocated variables (`y` was allocated on stack) are destroyed. That also answer your second question about memory leak, there is no memory leak. As long as you work with stack, allocation and deallocation is done "automagically" as destructor calls are inserted at the end of the scope (usually) by compiler.

- Example 1 Case 2:

The very same thing as in case 1. Your returned value is compromised because you returned stack allocated variable that is no longer valid as you return from function. Now you can observe this because between assigning and reading that value you make a function call. Depending on where original `y` was allocated that bit of memory might be reused during std::cout call. This become obvious as you work on the very same bit of memory cause of reference usage. Remember when you reached `}` of `createInt()`, you free that bit of memory. As an additional excersise, put a break point on lines `int &x = createInt();` and `int x = createInt();` then step into function and watch memory state as you leave it.

- Example 2 Case 1:

Now you create (potential) memory leak. You allocate a memory on heap so it won't be destroyed as you leave function body. You also pass that exact memory address, so you also should take responsibility for freeing it and you don't call `delete`, so that's your memory leak. And one more problem occurs as you assign returned value to completely new stack allocated variable. Your original `x` from `createInt()` is allocated, then returned by reference but feed to **assign operator** to other independent variable (`int x` have different address than `int* y`). Again you can check this with help of breakpoints and debugger.

- Example 2 Case 2:

Now this is almost proper use of variables returned by reference and assignment of them. You create variable `x` on heap, then return it's address and assign it to `y`. Problem being as `x` was created on stack you are responsible for destroying it so call to `delete` is neccessary to avoid memory leak. Put a break point and track memory addresses of both `x` and `y`. They are the same.

General rule of thumb is that **return by reference** should be used only with variables that exist outside of function, for example you can use it for class memebrs as they live inside the object or for global or static variables. For other purposes use **return by value**, unless you really need that very object, then return it **by pointer**. And while you work with pointers always be aware that someone at some point have to delete underlying variable.

I skip the part about vectors and instead point you a good tool for tracking memory leaks. It's not the best solution by any means, but for starters it will do the trick (assuming you are using Visual Studio).

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019

Remember to use breakpoints and debugger instead of printing everything to output/console. This will help you a lot. In both tracking memory and variable state, and understanding what your code really does.

Comment: Example 1 is undefined behavior, so your description of what happens may or not be true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the impression you have a real question at all, because you seem yo have found out all tricks, traps and good practices on your own. You seem to know about memory leaks and dangling references. Static and dynamic allocation. Most of your assumptions seem correct. Some hints though :
* references '&' and raw pointers result in exactly the same machine instructions, but they are hints to the programmers. Indeed, a method returning a reference likely means you don't have to take ownership for that reference, but without documentation there is no guarantee on the lifetime of that object. A raw pointer may represent a heap instance, or an optional argument, but it could also represent just a reference. This lack of ownership rules in C/C++ is indeed tricky.
* When dereferencing a dangling reference, the behavior is undefined. It may be working perfectly on your machine and it could burn my harddisk. Anything goes.
* When dealing with heap allocations, we nowadays prefer yo use smart pointers whenever possible. There is no mistaking in it's usage. Search for unique_ptr and shared_ptr
* Finally I recomy learning a bit of Rust. This is a programming language that was specifically designed to resolve such object lifetime/ownership issues. It is quite easy to install and run the most basic examples. Just try returning a dangling reference with Rust, you'll learn a lot, believe me.